# How to place a widget with the `y` from the title bar?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am placing some widgets in `tkinter` using the `place` geometry manager but the problem is that the `place` manager takes coordinates with reference from other point while I have the mouse position from the title bar. How do I do it?

[image]

Here, I have the distances from point A while the `place` manager requires from point B. How should I do that? `x` distance is not a problem since both are the same. The problem arises when I have to change the `y`. Is there a uniform solution rather than just trying some random values and selecting the one that fits the best?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use coordinates from the top of the title bar. If the user changes the height of the title bar via their window manager then all your coordinates will become invalid.

Comment: @PM2Ring Okay, then would it be possible to find out the length of the title bar so that I can subtract it?

Comment: Your window manager may provide a ruler app. Eg, for KDE there's [kruler](https://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/kruler/). Failing that, take a screen capture, and measure it in a paint program or image editor.

Comment: @PM2Ring Great! Thanks.

Comment: why is it important to use `place` in such a precise way? Tkinter's other geometry managers `pack` and `grid` make for a much more maintainable program that gracefully handles font changes, differences in resolution, etc.